# Keep ssh connection in a bash script alive

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, rsync

I have a bash script that has some logic which needs to be done locally and remotely. Hence, multiple ssh and rsync (for data transfer) calls are done, e.g.:

```
 command_0
 rsync ... # Data to remote
 ssh remote command_1
 rsync ... # Receive results
 ...
 # Above pattern is repeated multiple times
```

I have some issues regarding broken ssh connections due to `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`. The above script is also triggered ~30 times for different data sets asynchronously. How can I keep my ssh connection alive throughout one call of the script to decrease creations of ssh connections?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by enabling TCPKeepALive. Add something like the following to your command-line

```
ssh -o TCPKeepAlive=yes -o ServerAliveInterval=50
```

Or you can modify your  ~/.ssh/config and add

Host *

ServerAliveInterval 50

Comment: This won't have any effect at the "ssh_exchange_identification" point of the SSH protocol. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ssh/2926/debugging-ssh-problems/25955/ssh-exchange-identification-connection-closed-by-remote-host#t=201701112330597870699

Comment: I have already configured that in my .ssh/config prior writing my question. I was more of thinking to start-up one connection, get some sort of id and release/reacquire the connection on each successive call.